# Nested for loops in Matlab GPU programming

Tags: matlab, nested-loops, gpu, gnu-parallel

I want to run this specific nested for loop in GPU using matlab, can anyboy help me,

```
        Phi=rand(100,100); FluxD=rand(100,100); FluxC=rand(100,100);
        Ima = 100;
        Jma = 100;

        for i=1:Ima-1
             for j=1:Jma-1
                  Phi(i,j) =Phi(i,j)+dt*(FluxD(i,j)-FluxC(i,j));
             end
         end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things here - firstly, build your data on the GPU, and then for best performance, operate on it in a vectorised manner, like this:

```
% Build input data arrays directly on the GPU
Phi = rand(100, 'gpuArray');
FluxD = rand(100, 'gpuArray');
FluxC = rand(100, 'gpuArray');
Ima = 100;
Jma = 100;
% For convenience, make index vectors for i and j
ii = 1:Ima-1;
jj = 1:Jma-1;
% Compute Phi in a vectorised manner
Phi(ii, jj) = Phi(ii, jj) + dt * (FluxD(ii,jj) - FluxC(ii,jj));
```